# Optimize Query - Select COUNT and SUM from the same subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, subquery, query-optimization

I tried to find the solution to this on Stackoverflow, maybe my wording is wrong.

I have a query which takes to long to execute. I am sure there are simple ways to improve it. For example, I use the same sub-query twice for displaying two different columns (sum and count) but encountered several errors while trying to solve it on my own.

```
SELECT u.ID,
u.user_email AS mail, 
u.user_login AS userName, 
u.user_registered  AS signUpDate, 
(select meta_value from wp_usermeta where user_id = u.ID and meta_key = 'first_name' limit 1) as firstName, 
(select meta_value from wp_usermeta where user_id = u.ID and meta_key = 'last_name' limit 1) as lastName, 
(select meta_value from wp_usermeta where user_id = u.ID and meta_key = 'billing_phone' limit 1) as billingPhone, 
(select meta_value from wp_usermeta where user_id = u.ID and meta_key = 'shipping_phone' limit 1) as shippingPhone, 
(SELECT COUNT(meta_value) from wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_order_total' and post_id IN (select post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_value = u.ID and meta_key = '_customer_user')) as orderCount,
(SELECT SUM(meta_value) from wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_order_total' and post_id IN (select post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_value = u.ID and meta_key = '_customer_user')) as moneySpent 
FROM wp_users u;
```

Comment: I would suggest that you simplify the query to determine where the performance issue is.  That is, remove subqueries and see what affect.  I would *guess* that it is the last two subqueries, but I don't know your data or data model.

Comment: you are right, it is the two subqueries. isn't there a way to get two columns in one go, as COUNT and SUM uses the exact same subquery?

Comment: . . You should edit the question.  Such important information should not only be in the comments.

Comment: WP's meta tables are inefficiently indexed.  Use this plugin to get more speed:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Timur, as per your question in the comments of the first answer; you'd have to do something like this. You still need joins but you don't need as many for the `wp_usermeta` table. You will still need to join to `wp_postmeta` twice, because you can't do a join on the '_customer_user' `meta_key` and simultaneously retrieve the '_order_total' `meta_key` in a single join.

Just a note on the `MAX(CASE WHEN um.meta_key = '...' THEN um.meta_value END)` logic; it's the equivalent to `MAX(CASE WHEN um.meta_key = '...' THEN um.meta_value ELSE NULL END)`.

```sql
SELECT    u.ID, 
          u.user_email AS mail,
          u.user_login AS userName,
          u.user_registered AS signUpDate,
          MAX(CASE WHEN um.meta_key = 'first_name'     THEN um.meta_value END) AS firstName, 
          MAX(CASE WHEN um.meta_key = 'last_name'      THEN um.meta_value END) AS lastName, 
          MAX(CASE WHEN um.meta_key = 'billing_phone'  THEN um.meta_value END) AS billingPhone, 
          MAX(CASE WHEN um.meta_key = 'shipping_phone' THEN um.meta_value END) AS shippingPhone,
          COUNT(pval.meta_value) AS orderCount,
          SUM(pval.meta_value) AS moneySpent
FROM      wp_users AS u
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS um   ON u.ID = um.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm   ON u.ID = pm.meta_value      AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pval ON pm.post_id = pval.post_id AND pval.meta_key = '_order_total'
WHERE     (um.meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name', 'billing_phone', 'shipping_phone') 
           OR um.meta_key IS NULL)
GROUP BY  u.ID, 
          u.user_email,
          u.user_login,
          u.user_registered;
```

I'm not 100% sure on the logic. Let me know if it needs tweaking

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your query is that you have nested correlated sub queries. Correlated sub queries are a huge hit to SQL performance. In this case you want to try use joins with aggregation (`group by`).

I don't understand the intricacies of the schema your database, so I'm not quite sure why you're limiting the sub queries for `firstName` etc to 1 record. I can edit the answer to accommodate that if you give more detail.

I would suggest you try something like this:

```sql
SELECT   u.ID,
         u.user_email AS mail, 
         u.user_login AS userName, 
         u.user_registered  AS signUpDate, 
         mfn.meta_value as firstName, 
         mln.meta_value as lastName, 
         mbp.meta_value as billingPhone, 
         msp.meta_value as shippingPhone, 
         COUNT(pval.meta_value) as orderCount,
         SUM(pval.meta_value) as moneySpent 
FROM     wp_users u
JOIN     wp_usermeta as mfn  ON u.ID = mfn.user_id  AND mfn.meta_key = 'first_name'
JOIN     wp_usermeta as mln  ON u.ID = mln.user_id  AND mln.meta_key = 'last_name'
JOIN     wp_usermeta as mbp  ON u.ID = mbp.user_id  AND mbp.meta_key = 'billing_phone'
JOIN     wp_usermeta as msp  ON u.ID = msp.user_id  AND msp.meta_key = 'shipping_phone'
JOIN     wp_postmeta as p    ON p.meta_value = u.ID AND p.meta_key = '_customer_user'
JOIN     wp_postmeta as pval ON pval.post_id = p.post_id AND pval.meta_key = '_order_total'
GROUP BY u.ID,
         u.user_email, 
         u.user_login, 
         u.user_registered, 
         mfn.meta_value, 
         mln.meta_value, 
         mbp.meta_value, 
         msp.meta_value
```

*As per [@O.Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205608/o-jones)'s comment, consider using LEFT JOINS instead of INNER JOINS so that the query still returns results where a `meta_value` is missing.*

Comment: Good answer. One suggestion: using LEFT JOIN rather than ordinary inner JOIN will allow the result set to contain rows where some metadata (e.g. billing_phone) is missing. The LIMIT 1 issue is an attempt to deal with the remote possibility of duplicate metadata rows. The [WordPress schema](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) permits those dups, but most applications don't

Comment: Hi @O.Jones, thanks for the suggestion. Agreed, LEFT JOINS are probably better.
I see the issue with the usermeta table and there isn't a modified / created / expired date.

Comment: Thank you both!
It works well and i have learned something.
does it change something performancewise using LIMIT 1?

Comment: It's not LIMIT ` that smacks down performance, it's the nested subqueries.

Comment: @Timur you can use wp_usermeta table single time instead of 4 times.

Comment: Sure @Timur. I'm actually more versed with SQL Server so I'm not quite sure about the performance impact of the LIMIT clause. There's a [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52079/does-using-limit-improve-the-performance-and-is-it-noticeable) on the Database Administrators Stack Exchange about this and Percona has a [blog article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/01/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-optimization/) on performance optimisation with ORDER BY and LIMIT if you're interested.

Comment: @RahulBiswas, it wouldn't be a good way to go about it. You need to join to the `wp_usermeta` table four times because of the table's design. Its using a kind of key-value pair schema. So you need a join for each key, for which you want the value, in your query.

Comment: At first thanks Timur for such a good question and also thanks @Jason for such a brilliant answer. As userid is existed in that table so query like SELECT user_id, MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name' THEN meta_value END) firstName , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'last_name' THEN meta_value END) lastName
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'billing_phone' THEN meta_value END) billingPhone
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'shipping_phone' THEN meta_value END) shippingPhone FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name', 'billing_phone', 'shipping_phone') GROUP BY user_id

Comment: @Jason you can use it in your query to check whether it works or not. I'll not post it as an answer.

Comment: @RahulBiswas, I see how you're doing it. It actually takes care of the potential duplicates that may exist in `wp_usermeta`. I'm not sure on the performance impact though. I encourage you to post it as an answer.

Comment: @RahulBiswas the approach is interesting for me, i tried to complete the query you proposed with the rest of data i need to gather. I wasnt able to include the other table and do the sum and count...

Comment: @RahulBiswas could you post the complete query as a solution?

Comment: @Jason or do you understand how to combine the approach of Rahul with your answer?

Comment: @Timur, I've added a second answer to demonstrate combining using `MAX(CASE...`

Comment: @Timur please check my query.

Comment: thank you, i will test it tomorrow and give give some feedback

Answer (score 0):

Here subquery has been introduced for minimizing multiple times using a single table and removing few column from **GROUP BY** clause for optimization purpose. Use **WHERE** clause in every subquery if need a particular user/ few users or any searching condition. If subquery returns no data but needed user info then use **LEFT JOIN** instead of **INNER JOIN**.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT u.ID
     , u.user_email AS mail
     , u.user_login AS userName
     , u.user_registered  AS signUpDate
     , t.firstName
     , t.lastName
     , t.billingPhone
     , t.shippingPhone
     , r.orderCount
     , r.moneySpent
FROM wp_users u      
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id
                 , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name' THEN meta_value END) firstName 
                 , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'last_name' THEN meta_value END) lastName 
                 , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'billing_phone' THEN meta_value END) billingPhone 
                 , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'shipping_phone' THEN meta_value END) shippingPhone 
            FROM wp_usermeta 
            WHERE meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name', 'billing_phone', 'shipping_phone') 
            GROUP BY user_id) t
       ON u.ID = t.user_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT p.meta_value
                 , COUNT(pval.meta_value) as orderCount
                 , SUM(pval.meta_value) as moneySpent 
            FROM wp_postmeta as p
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pval
                    ON p.post_id = pval.post_id
                   AND p.meta_key = '_customer_user'
                   AND pval.meta_key = '_order_total'
            GROUP BY p.meta_value) r
        ON u.ID = r.meta_value;
```