# How to do joins on multiple columns in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a 'response' table with many columns, some of those columns take an integer value which corresponds to another 'answer' table. Here is the response table:

TABLE response:

```
name      | answer1 | answer2 | answer3
----------------------------------
james foo | 1       | 2       | 3
```

TABLE answers_ref:

```
id | answer 
------------
1  | Yes
2  | No
3  | Maybe
```

So I want to be able to get the answers from james foo, the results should be

```
name      | answer1 | answer2 | answer3
----------------------------------
james foo | Yes     | No      | Maybe
```

Here is the query that i tried:

```
select t1.name, al.answer, al2.answer FROM response t1 LEFT JOIN answers_ref al ON t1.answer1 = al.id LEFT JOIN answers_ref al2 ON t1.answer2 = al2.id;
```

The above works to get 2 answers, but I have to do a third join to get answer3, but what if I have 10 answers/columns?

Comment: You need 10 joins, unless you change the design of the table.

Comment: Use pivot table if answer column not fixed.

Comment: in my humble oppinion its very bad database design. You should change it now if its not too late.

Comment: You can get idea by checking my query where table used single time and multi row value converted to multi column. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69268254/optimize-query-select-count-and-sum-from-the-same-subquery/69627086#69627086

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers but I decided take the advice of almost everyone so I decided to just insert the actual string answer to the response table rather than using integer references. I have talked with my front end to get them to send me string instead, or I can do select query the answers_ref table beforehand and insert that. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

This one works. I tested:

```
SELECT r.name, 
  (SELECT answer FROM answers_ref WHERE id = r.answer1) as answer1, 
  (SELECT answer FROM answers_ref  WHERE id = r.answer2) as answer2, 
  (SELECT answer FROM answers_ref  WHERE id = r.answer3) as answer3
FROM response r
WHERE name = 'James Foo';
```

Comment: Reading the documentation that says a subquery can be used in the SELECT clause, FROM clause and WHERE clause made me test it out. Never used it before. Thanks for the very good question.

Comment: OP is asking _"but what if I have 10 answers/columns?"_ ; which seem to mean that OP is probably trying to find a solution where they don't need to worry about adding/removing a line in the query whenever there's a new column.

Comment: The reponse table has a fixed number of columns and he wants a one to one replacement of the id with the value. It's a straight lookup table which is the job of a subquery. Of course he could do it programmatically, look up everything from the answers_ref table (it's only 3 rows) and cache it in code and later replace the anwer ids with the corresponding values. No need JOINs.

Comment: I'm not talking about whether to use join or not. OP have already practiced that in their query and your suggestion (without join) is an alternative to that. What I see is both of the queries need to be maintained whenever there's new column added/removed. Otherwise the query will return error, right?

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, yes your solution does indeed work and in my opinion your query is more readable than my multiple joins, but as I said above I have many columns so it is still cumbersome to type all the column names.

Comment: Thank you for asking the original question. Maybe this solution does not satisfy your exact needs but it gives me an intellectual exercise on how to use subqueries in the SELECT clause. Maybe someone in the future who comes across this page will find that this solution exactly answers their problem

Answer (score 0):

You canot achieve that with less joins. Each column is treated separately and they don't magically somehow share "join" values between them.

The rue is simple - one join per column, that's it. You can't get any simplier or shorter than this.

So the answer is: that's not possible.

Comment: You can achieve it with ZERO joins. See below.

Comment: @RoslanAmir Those subqueries are even worse performance wise. And are less readable than joins.

Comment: I think JOINs are worse performance-wise than subqueries.

Comment: Well, that's not matter of what you or me think :) it's matter of fact.